# Criar máscara em FrameLayout

Tags: android, mask

Fala galera,

Eu tenho uma imagem, e gostaria de criar uma máscara,  mas estou com dificuldades.

**1-** Eu tenho essa imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2-** Eu gostaria de não mexer no tamanho original da imagem, e apresentar só um pedaço dela, assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como devo proceder? Tenho que colocar a imagem em um framelayout e mascarar o frame?

**Obs:** Pensei no FrameLayout, pois depois através de botões, vou movimentar a imagem que está dentro do Frame.

Abraços.

Comment: Colocar a imagem em background em uma div e depois dar altura, largura e border-radius, não resolve seu caso?

Comment: @DanieldeAndradeVarela Como assim uma "div"? Eu não consigo fazer com um FrameLayout? Eu penso nele pois preciso movimentar a imagem que está dentro da máscara depois, ela funcionaria como um zoom, conforme o usuário for movendo o dedo na imagem original, eu ia setando X e Y no zoom máscarado também.

Comment: Me desculpe, eu pensei que você estava fazendo em HTML + CSS + JS, agora que me toquei que esta fazendo uma aplicação nativa com Java para Android (correto?).

Comment: Isso, estou fazendo em Java para Android